# Vishwamitra common link Ramayan and Mahabharata

Tags: hindu

As per Ramayan, Ram and Laxman helped Vishwamitra to kill Tataka yakshi. Viswamitra was a sage by then, that means he had already met Menaka, and Shakuntala was born.
As per Mahabharata Shakuntala was married to Dushmanta and gave birth to Bharat. This means, Dushyanta or Bharat must have been alive in the same timeline as Ram. If so, why is there no mention of either of them in Ramayan? How come there is no mention of Ram in the mention of Dushyanta and his son Bharat’s timeline in Mahabharata? What am I missing?